# Firestore serverTimestamp() stopped working

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Below stopped working after moving from version `^10.0.2` to `^11.2.0` of `firebase-admin`.

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
const serverTimestamp = firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

How should it be done now? Can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `FieldValue` from Firestore SDK as shown below:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { FieldValue, getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

initializeApp();

const serverTimestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

The API reference can be found [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.serverTimestamp).